# Let $A$ be a square matrix and $A=BC$ be its rank factorization. Show that rank $(A)$=rank $(A^2)$ if and only if $CB$ is non-singular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $A$ be a square matrix and $A=BC$ be its rank factorization. Show that rank $(A)$=rank $(A^2)$ if and only if $CB$ is non-singular.

please give a hint.

My approach : Suppose that rank $(A)$=rank $(A^2)$. This implies range $A$=range $A^2$. Now from this how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** What can we say about $\operatorname{range}(B) \cap \ker(C)$?

Alternatively, note that $A^2 = B[CB]C$.

---

One approach is as follows. Let $A$ be $n \times n$ with rank $r$, so that $B$ is $n \times r$ and $C$ is $r \times n$.

Suppose that $\operatorname{rank}(CB) < r$ (i.e. $CB$ is singular). It follows that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A^2) = \operatorname{rank}(B(CB)C) \leq \operatorname{rank}(CB) < r = \operatorname{rank}(A).
$$
On the other hand, suppose that $CB$ is non-singular.  It follows that
$$
\operatorname{rank}((CB)C) = \operatorname{rank}(C) = r.
$$
Now, using the fact that that $B$ has a trivial kernel, conclude that
$$
\operatorname{rank}(A^2) = \operatorname{rank}(B[CBC])  = 
\operatorname{rank}(CBC) = r.
$$

Comment: ok. Will you please more elaborate.

Comment: @nimidutta Did you try to move forward with either of these hints?

Comment: yes. I tried to proceed but could not

Comment: @nimi See my latest edit

Comment: @nimi The alternative is to use [the approach suggested here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/846178/81360)

Comment: @nimi See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2154624/81360) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2150462/81360)